# INNER JOIN custom tables - SQL Query

Tags: wp-query, mysql, page-template

H, I am trying to get results from two tables with INNER JOIN in WordPress theme template file, but I don't know what's I am doing wrong. Please help me, here is the code below

```
global $wpdb;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$sql= "SELECT client_id FROM quotes INNER JOIN client_info ON quotes.client_id = client_info.id WHERE user_id =".$user_id;
// user_id column has the data current user_id in it
 $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  print_r($results); // results displays an empty array but both tables have data
```

Comment: there is no table "quotes" in WordPress then this question may be not related to wordpress ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, these both are custom table I created in phpmyadmin

Comment: What's the table name where column ```user_id``` is?

Comment: user_id is in quotes table

Comment: Is this column integer or (var)char? Does the query return values in phpMyAdmin (like is it true anyhow)?

Comment: Inner Join query returns empty array,

Comment: tyr with adding quotes.user_id in sql query. **$sql= "SELECT quotes.client_id FROM quotes INNER JOIN client_info ON quotes.client_id = client_info.id WHERE quotes.user_id =".$user_id;**

Comment: I tried also but failed to load query in WordPress